# Работа с doc и xls файлами в git и их конфликты

Tags: git

Есть ли возможность корректной работы с doc и xls файлами в *git*?
Есть ли инструмент, который бы позволил как-то посмотреть разницу между тем файлом xls, что был и тем, что есть? Особенно это интересует когда происходят конфликты в файлах. Когда, например doc файл содержит текст, то *SourceTree* может показать какие изменения я сейчас внёс файл. Однако с xls это уже сработает. А при конфликтах даже *SourceTree* уже не покажет где что не так, он предлагает просто открыть файл ДО и файл ПОСЛЕ.

Как можно корректно работать с такими форматами файлов в гит? Можно ли? Или не имеет смысла? И как разрешать конфликты? И есть ли графический интерфейс для решения этих конфликтов такого вида файлов?

Comment: Вы выбрали неправильный инструмент для решения ваших задач (это может быть и формат документа `*.doc` или подобный, это может быть и система хранения `Git` или подобная).

Comment: В теории MS Word умеет сравнивать документы, а git умеет вызывать внешние команды. Посмотрите на https://stackoverflow.com/q/2606467/1016033

Answer (score 2):

Никак нельзя. Гит - для текстовых файлов. Doc и xls таковыми не являются, так же как и, например, изображения, исполняемые бинарники и архивы.

Это не значит, что такие файлы нельзя хранить в репозитории. Можно (хотя без особой необходимости не нужно). Но это будут отдельные файлы без истории и версионирования.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению насколько я знаю, нет таких функций.

Мне мало приходилось с таким работать, но помогало делать так : 
 - Создаем новую ветку (если нам нужно обновить файл) - от мастера к примеру; 
 - Изменяем файл - Сохраняем; 
 - Мержим в мастер.

Такие проблемы часто возникают с шифрованными файлами (как пример ansible-vault ) 
Так же и exel - если вы отроете сравнение файла оригинала и во втором вы измените пару символов - файл будет на 100% разный..